# PHP não reconhece todos os arquivos do input multiple

Tags: php, input, multiple

Bom dia, estou fazendo uma função para fazer o upload de várias imagens, mas no PHP chega apenas a última. Aqui estão meus códigos:

HTML

```
 <form id="msform" action="../controllers/controllerCadastraImagemProduto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type='file' name="imagensPB[]" multiple>

 </form>
```

PHP

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_FILES["imagensPB"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['imagensPB']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Make sure we have a filepath
if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//Setup our new file path
$newFilePath = "../img/produtos/" . $_FILES['imagensPB']['name'] [$i];

//Upload the file into the temp dir
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {


}
}
$i++;
}
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Veja a estrutura do array com, `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Olá, tentei e apareceu isso: Array ( [imagensPB] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 2.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php8358.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 86060 ) ) )

Comment: você esta armazenando a imagem (com nome temporario) em uma variavel string e nao em um array, entao toda vez que o foreach passa por `$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['imagensPB']['tmp_name'][$i];` ele reescreve a variavel...

Comment: Entendi Rafael obrigado. Vou mudar o código.

Answer (score 0):

Caso não ache uma solução você pode tentar usar o Uploadify. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)